# Set up better workflow in Excel

Tags: database, excel

Okay. I was looking at my physio's spreadsheets for his small, private business today. He uses Excel to keep track of his clients appointments, fees, attendences, medical reports etc. At the moment he has a single sheet where he adds every clients appointment to the list as he goes - there's 3 years of details, one row for every appointment! It's huge and pretty hard to navigate and make sense of when he's extracting information such as fees paid/unpaid, total visits, etc.

I'm a novice to sub-intermediate at Excel, but getting better. What I'm wondering is it possible to set up a "front page" where he can enter a day's details in a single spreadsheet, press an export cell,and then have Excel pass the relevant data to individual sheets for each client. The data on that front page would look for the clients name as a string to find the relevant sheet and drop the information in.
I'm not asking how to do it as such, but rather wondering if this is possible at all!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 =COUNTIF(Sheet1!RangeToLookThrough, ValueYoureLookingFor)
```

Put this where you want.

If you want a daily dashboard, you could replicate this to do something like  :

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!B2:B4000<>""),--(MONTH(Sheet1!B2:B4000)=9))
```

Feel free to alter this to capture yesterday or whatever date your looking for. I just used an old report to mess with and give you an example.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a play around!